# Bootstrap Navigation Bar - Vertical, expected Horizontal

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4

Using essentially the same css classes that are used on the twitter bootstrap site itself (and many other places), my horizontal navbar becomes vertical. I have the same div layout and classes (except the bs-* classes) as on the bootstrap page.

I hacked around this once by changing various settings from "block" to "inline" and such but there must be a better solution. Please advise.

**Navbar html:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- 
         <div class = "navbar-header">
             <a class = "navbar-brand"> Home </a>
         </div>
    -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="">Followers</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">Posts</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap 4, then use a Bootstrap 4 Navbar: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/

Answer (score 1):

This has been copied from bootstrap's navbar documentation. And hence it is responsive by default (show the preview in full-screen to by clicking `Full page` button on top right corner of the preview). If you don't require `Branding` to be there, you will just need to remove `<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Branding</a>`.

More information about bootstrap 4's navbar can be found here - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Branding</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Followers<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Posts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```